# Have the proofs in Buss's "On Goedel’s Theorems on Lengths of Proofs" been formalized (mechanically checked)?

Tags: proof-complexity, coq, proof-assistants, agda

The paper [On Gödel's theorems on lengths of proofs I: Number of lines and speedup for arithmetics](https://doi.org/10.2307/2275906) contains quite interesting results on proof length. But some of the details are still, to me, a bit fuzzy [I now find a lot of non-formalized mathematics a bit fuzzy, an occupational hazard it seems].

There is a [somewhat related thread](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40603/formalization-of-proofs-and-computational-complexity-paradox) on here, but it doesn't link to machine-checked formalizations.

Comment: I don’t follow formalized mathematics, but it’s extremely unlikely. In this field, pretty much nothing at all has been formalized.